# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/platform-browser/animations'

Tags: angular, webpack, gulp, yarnpkg

Recently updated from Angular 12 to latest & updated respective package.json references to latest as well

**Error:**

```
 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/platform-browser/animations' in 'C:\MySolution\AngApp\Client\AppName\src'
```

I'm using Yarn & Gulp with webpack in combination.

Update 1: Sample Test App everything works as expected but when i work on Real application i get the above error.

I suspect something to do with Gulp how it does things any advice would be helpful.

Happy to add more details if required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Fixed the issue:**

**Root Cause:** Angular.json having a extra brace causing this whole mess somehow earlier webpack seem to ignore this. Error thrown is irrelevant to what's happened in real.

Updated Yarn to 3.2.4 & WebPack to 5.74

Answer (score 0):

import this module from angular to app.module

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

imports: [BrowserAnimationsModule]
```

Comment: I've the above configuration already